# Find data attribute and insert it to database using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I need a correct script for iserting data attribute to database onclick using ajax.

**HTML:**

```
<li><a data-cat="random name">Button</a></li>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('li a').click(function() {
  $(this).data('cat');
  // Dont know how correctly use ajax here.
});
```

**PHP:**

```
$cat = HERE MUST BE DATA ATTRIBUTE;
$timer = time();
$something = NULL;

$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO table (cat, timer, something) VALUES(:cat, :timer, :something)");
$stmt->execute(array(':cat' => $cat, ':timer' => $timer, ':something' => $something,));
```

Sorry for bad english, and thanks for any answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More info at about [jQuery.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

```
$('li a').click(function() {
    var category = $(this).data('cat');
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: '/script.php',
      data: {'cat': category}
    });
});
```

PHP

```
$cat = $_POST['cat'];
```